# How to save APK file of my own app in sd-card and share it via bluetooth? (only by using code and intent)

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, apk, sd-card

Here, in my country, there is no access to Google Play. I have written a FREE useful app for my people, and some days after its release, I concluded that the best way to make it more reachable, is to **share it's APK file via bluetooth** *(because sharing files by bluetooth is very popular here!)*

Now, the problem is:

> **How can I (by code) save a copy of the running APK file in sd card, and then use some intent to prepare the file for sharing by
>   bluetooth?**

Unfortunately, I haven't yet tried any code, because simply I don't know where to start from.
So just the starting points or some hints are very welcome!

**EDIT:** Some of my users, are more technical and know that they can use a **FileManager/Bluetoth Sharing app** to send the APK to their freinds, but I want anyone be able to simply share the app by just clicking a button in the app, even if they are rookies or haven't any file manager on their device.

Comment: Our [Bazaar project](https://dev.guardianproject.info/projects/bazaar/wiki) aims to turn [FDroid](https://f-droid.org) into an app store for people who can't access Google Play. I'm working on adding Bluetooth APK sharing to FDroid right now, in fact, that's where my example code comes from.  Specifically, you will probably be interested in [running your own FDroid repo](https://guardianproject.info/2013/11/05/setting-up-your-own-app-store-with-f-droid/) for your app so users automatically get updates, and also getting your app into the official FDroid repo, if its Free Software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a standard `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` using the installed location of your app, and make that `Intent` explicitly targeted to Bluetooth, you can do this.  You can see how here:

[Bluetooth File transfer on Android(even restricted types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277593/bluetooth-file-transfer-on-androideven-restricted-types/21790899#21790899)

Comment: Thanks, after months I have returned to this Q by accident and found my answer based on your answer in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

By code seems to be overkill in your situation. Maybe just using a file/app sharing app over bluetooth would be enough : http://www.guidingtech.com/10346/transfer-android-apps-between-phones-bluetooth/

Comment: Why don't you send them a link to your apk, somewhere on the internet. They will be able to install it much more simply, at least it will be much simpler for you... :)

Comment: Thanks again, that solution is my "Plan B", but before using it, I want to know whether I can use that bluetooth sharing option or not. I'm sure my users would prefer bluetooth option (It's easier for them!), but I know that your solution is easier for me.